# Convert Key/Pair RDD to yield sum of values, min and max values in each group using Python SPark

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to Spark, I have the below RDD

```
(2, 2.0)
(2, 4.0)
(2, 1.5)
(2, 6.0)
(2, 7.0)
(2, 8.0)
```

I tried to convert it to `(2, 28.5, 1.5, 8)`
where `2` is the key Value, followed by `28.5` a sum of all values, `1.5` as the minimum value and `8` being the max. Needless to say I have failed to do it.

I have followed the below approaches :

```
custValuesX = lines.map(parsedLines).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x+y,x-y,min(x,y)))
```

I get error :

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple
```

I tried this

```
custValuesX = lines.map(parsedLines)
                   .mapValues(lambda x: (x,1))
                   .reduceByKey(lambda y,x: ( x[0]+y[0], min(y[0],x[0]) ))
```

and the result is

```
(2, (28.5, 8.0, 20.5))
```

I understand the `8.0` , as it is the last value in the pair, but whats the deal with `20.5`?

Would really appreciate if some one would try to help/explain.

Comment: Hey , thanks for directing me to the answer, it worked ..

Comment: Could you please explain the error
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple